# Blender, was installed with dnf not support CUDA

Tags: gpu, linux

**OS. Linux Fedora 27**

Today I bought GTX650Ti and connected it instead of 9600GT. I have reinstall drivers, and install CUDA packages. 
The fact is that Blender, downloaded as archive and unpacked can use CUDA. This applies to 2.79, 2.73 and other versions.
But copy of Blender, installed with

```
]$ dns install blender
```

does not have a option choose CUDA.

Reboot the system did not help.

Comment: Are you using the proprietary Nvidia drivers? The open source ones do not enable cuda.

Comment: @cegaton, of course, I use proprietary drivers. I wrote: The fact is that Blender, downloaded as archive and unpacked can use CUDA. This applies to 2.79, 2.73 and other versions.